Generalizing LCA in DAGs to Include Proximity and Special Cases
I’m working on a problem involving Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) where I need to compute a generalization of the Lowest Common Ancestor (LCA). Traditional definitions of LCA in DAGs, which focus solely on partial order minimality, miss certain cases that are important to my application.
Problem Description:
I want to identify all "proximal" shared ancestors of two nodes that balance:
1. Partial Order Minimality: The node is not dominated by any other common ancestor of the given nodes.
2. Graph Proximity: The node is among those with minimal total graph distance to the queried nodes.

digraph {
    a -> e;
    a -> f;
    a -> g;
    a -> h;
    b -> g;
    b -> e;
    e -> g;
    e -> h;
    f -> h;
    c -> e;
    d -> g;
    d -> h;
}


Classical LCAs: Nodes d and e, as they are minimal in the partial order of all common ancestors.
Two-Level Proximal Shared Ancestor Classification
Perfect Proximal Shared Ancestors:
These are common ancestors that are:
    Minimal in the partial order.
    Minimize the graph distance to both queried nodes.

Partial Proximal Shared Ancestors:
These are common ancestors that minimize graph distance to only one queried node but are not optimal for the other.

Analysis of g and h:
Common Ancestors:
{a,b,c,d,e}

Distances to g:
    a→g: 1 hop
    b→g: 1 hop
    e→g: 1 hop
    c→g: 2 hops via e
    d→g: 1 hop

Distances to h:
    a→h: 1 hop
    b→h: 2 hops via e
    e→h: 1 hop
    c→h: 2 hops via e
    d→h: 1 hop

Results:
Perfect Proximal Shared Ancestors:
    a,d,e
        These nodes are minimal in the partial order and have the shortest total distances to both g and h.

Partial Proximal Shared Ancestors:
    b
        b→g: 1 hop (optimal).
        b→h: 2 hops via e (not optimal).

Questions:

Is there an existing graph-theoretic concept or algorithm that generalizes LCA computation in DAGs to include both partial order minimality and graph proximity?
Are there references or research papers that explore such generalized ancestor queries?
What would be an efficient algorithm to address this problem?

